# is it possible to activate a div when clicked without javascript?

Tags: css

Just wondering if a div can be called without using javascript.

such as

```
my_div:hover{ add new layout}
```

is there a version for click eg

```
my_div:click{add new layout}
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope, but you can go the other way.  You might also be interested in something like: https://github.com/krasimir/cssx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you add `tabindex="0"` to your div, you make it clickable and can then use the `:focus` pseudo-class to apply styles.

```
<div class="clickable" tabindex="0"></div>

.clickable {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.clickable:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooVeOX). Clicking the div should give it focus and apply the :focus CSS to it. Clicking away from it will unfocus (blur) it and reset the default styles.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you can fake it using checkboxes:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #dadada;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked+label+.content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">Click me</label>
<div class="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
  <p>lorem20</p>
</div>
```